# c# 2d array in to datagrid view

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, datagridview

I'm trying to display the 2d array in datagridview. Im generting data via Windows Form into 2d array and then trying to display that data into datagrid view but I get an error  on line
 **row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);**
**Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control.**
not sure what im doing wrong appreciate if anyone please put me on the right direction
Code is below

```
   iArray = new String[2, 10];
            iArray = custDetails.pCustomDetails();


            int height = iArray.GetLength(0);
            int width = iArray.GetLength(1);
        MessageBox.Show(height.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(width.ToString());

        this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = width;

            for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            {

            row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);

                for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                {
                row.Cells[c].Value = iArray[r, c];

                }

                this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem here is that you are trying to add the **same instance** of row again and again in loop.

So this small fix will make yr code work

```
 for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
        {

         //Fix : create a new instance of row every time
          DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();


        row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);

            for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
            {
            row.Cells[c].Value = iArray[r, c];

            }

            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is the best one you can find, just rewrite it into C#:

```
'at first add columns to the dataGridView before insert rows in it
'y = number of the columns which should equal yourArray.getlength(0) - 1 
'you can change (col) to any type of column you need

        For i = 0 To y
            Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            col.DataPropertyName = "PropertyName" & i.ToString
            col.HeaderText = i.ToString
            col.Name = "colWhateverName" & i.ToString
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
        Next

'now you insert the rows
'exampleRow ={yourArray(0,0), yourArray(0,1), ..... ,yourArray(0,y)}
'x = number of rows

        For i = 0 To x
            Dim aarray As New List(Of String)
            For ii = 0 To y
                aarray.Add(yourArray(i, ii).ToString)
            Next
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(aarray.ToArray)
        Next
```

I do such an app you can check it here:
https://github.com/ammardab3an/Array-Rotate-90